Is There A Way to Suppress the "External name used to document parameter" Warning in Swift?
This is an annoyance, as opposed to anything critical.
I tend to use the standard headerdoc-style, in my Swift, like so:
/* ################################################# */
/**
 Perform a server-based search.
 
 - parameter specification: The search specification.
 - parameter completion: A tail completion proc (may be called in any thread).
 */
public func meetingAutoRadiusSearch(minimumNumberOfResults inMinNumber: Int, specification inSpecification: SearchSpecification, completion inCompletion: @escaping QueryResultCompletion) {

The issue is that the compiler gives this warning:

Now, I always use "in..." parameters for my APIs. It helps me to keep track of what comes in from outside the function. I seldom use the external name.
However, consumers of the function are only interested in the external name.
I'm puzzled as to why Xcode doesn't want me to use these.
Is there some way to suppress the warning, or am I doing something else wrong, here?
(Yeah, I still have to document the first parameter, which is why I am looking at this, now).

Because using the external name many times wouldn't make much sense? For instance when using generic words like by, from, in etc, then it makes much more sense to use the actual parameter name in the documentation. Example func multiply(_ value: Int, with factor: Int) -> Int. Of course it would be nice if we could make exceptions but I am not aware of any way to do so.

Yeah, as Sweeper noted, Swift wants you to use only one name for parameters, even though they give you the ability to have an "inside name." I tend to compile -wall, and I'm just glad that this warning doesn't bork the build.

+1 for the documentation mentioning, that the completion handler can be called on any thread (from within the function). I wished, there would be more awareness for this "subtle detail".  :)   With Swift 6, you would get errors if it is not safe.

According to the Swift API Design Guidelines, this is not how you should name parameters.

Choose parameter names to serve documentation. Even though parameter names do not appear at a function or method’s point of use, they play an important explanatory role.
Choose these names to make documentation easy to read. [...]

Parameter names are to "serve documentation", not (just) to serve you (the one who implements the function). Naming parameters this way is not "Swifty" at all.

If you want to mark which parameters are input, one way is to use a property wrapper like this:
@propertyWrapper
struct Input<T> {
    let wrappedValue: T
}

public func someFunction(@Input x: Int, @Input y: Int) {
    // ...
}

Though this doesn't make much sense to me - surely all non-inout parameters are "inputs"?

If you actually want a symbol that is named with a "in" prefix in your function, you can write a function body macro (here I called this InputParameterNames) which, when used like this:
@InputParameterNames
public func someFunction(@Input x: Int, @Input y: Int) {
    // ...
}

expands to
public func someFunction(@Input x: Int, @Input y: Int) {
    let inX = x
    let inY = y
    // ...
}

It would find parameters that are marked @Input in the parameters list, and generate a let declaration for each of them. I am not going to write an implementation of this macro in this answer, because I do not endorse writing Swift in this way.
For how to silence a warning, see this post. It is currently impossible at the time of writing.

Ugh. I'll greencheck this, as it's the correct answer, but not one I like. I've been doing this kind of thing for decades. It's an old pattern. I don't particularly care whether or not it's "swifty," as I'm the one that consumes my own code (I write code and documentation for myself). Ah...well. Thanks!

In fairness, that "old pattern" did serve a very useful purpose in C functions that could have "out parameters". I'm not sure it's particularly useful anymore, but it's certainly an artistic liberty you can enjoy in your own code

Yeah, I enjoy a lot of "artistic liberties." Us old fogeys are like that. Gets me a lot of eyerolls, but I ship a lot of stuff that works well.
